# UML class diagram: How to pass from relational diagram to class diagram

Tags: uml

I'm working on a design of a workout follow up program.I have the following relational diagram and I want to create a class diagram with it.

[image: relational diagram]

In this case I should create an associative table as follow:

[image: associativeTable]

To explain the relation: a muscle may be targeted by many different exercises and an exercise may target many muscle.

Is the following representation correct? Can we improve it?

[image: class diagram]

If it is not correct, can any one suggest the best way to represent it in a class diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagram is almost correct. You should replace all the occurrences of `List<...>` with association-end properties. To do this, you will need two associations. Here's an example:

[image]

I took the liberty of changing the multiplicity for the primaries. I think each direction has at least one. This shows why using associations is more expressive--with a `List<...>`, you cannot express min and max cardinalities.